# Is it possible to declare a subprocedure in the 'declare' block of PL/SQL developer test window?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I need to test a stored procedure that has several subprocedures in the `is` block. I have copied everything to a test window, however, putting these subprocedures in the `declare` block does not seem to work. When I attempt to call them from the `begin` block, I get an error saying that they have not been declared. I haven't changed anything other than moving the contents of `is` to `declare`. What can I do?

Comment: Update the question and post the code so we can be able to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare procedure, however:

1) You declare it without 'create or replace' keywords
2) If you declare any variables in the same block, all procedures and functions must be declared after the last variable declaration.

So, for example, this:

```
declare

   some_text varchar2(10) := 'SOME_TEXT';

   procedure print_4 is 

      x number := 4;
   begin
      dbms_output.put_line(x);
   end print_4;
begin
   print_4;
end;
```

is a valid pl/sql block, while this:

```
declare

   procedure print_4 is 

      x number := 4;
   begin
      dbms_output.put_line(x);
   end print_4;

   some_text varchar2(10) := 'SOME_TEXT';
begin
   print_4;
end;
```

is not.

If you post your code we might find some other errors.